# ax.get_xlim() doesnt work with datetimeindex

Tags: python, matplotlib

ax.get_xlim doesnt provide the right result. When running the code below, I get xmin as 1970-01-01 instead of 2003-01-01.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2023-01-01', freq='M'),
    'Value': np.random.rand(516)
})
data=data.set_index('Date')
data.index=pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data=data.resample('M').last()

data=data['2003-01-01':]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.plot(data)
print(pd.Timestamp(xmin))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should pull the xlims after the plot rather than before. Otherwise, it's just the default starting [0, 1].

Then you need to use `matplotlib.dates.num2date()`

```
from matplotlib import dates

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2023-01-01', freq='M'),
    'Value': np.random.rand(516)
})
data=data.set_index('Date')
data.index=pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data=data.resample('M').last()

data=data['2003-01-01':]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(data)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

print(dates.num2date(xmin))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 minor issues here:

1. The limits are not appropriately available until you actually plot the data, so you'll need to call `ax.get_xlim` AFTER `ax.plot`
2. Matplotlib converts datetimes into floats that represent the number of days after 1970-01-01, whereas pandas represents dates by the number of nanoseconds after 1970-01-01.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2023-01-01', freq='M'),
    'Value': np.random.rand(516)
})
data=data.set_index('Date')
data.index=pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data=data.resample('M').last()

data=data['2003-01-01':]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)

xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

# Using pandas mechanics to convert values
print(pd.Timestamp(xmin, unit='D')) # 2002-02-01 07:12:00

# Using matplotlib mechanics
from matplotlib.dates import num2date
print(num2date(xmin)) # 2002-02-01 07:12:00+00:00
```

To convert the values using `pd.Timestamp` or `pd.to_datetime` you'll need to specify the `unit='D'` to represent that each unit of the value is 1 day since the epoch (1970-01-01).

Alternatively, you can also use `matplotlib` built in date conversion function: `matplotlib.dates.num2date` to get a numpy datetime back.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add on to Michel Cao's response to provide a bit more insight as to what's happening.

From the [matplotlib documentation on date format](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format):

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since a default epoch of 1970-01-01 UTC; for example, 1970-01-01, 06:00 is the floating point number 0.25.

So if after correcting the order of our line execution as mentioned in the Cao's response. Running

```
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
```

Will result in `xmin == 11719.3`. This is the correct expected date, but just in the matplotlib floating point format. Calling [num2date](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) will convert our floating point number to the expected date of `2002-02-01 07:12:00+00:00`.